# graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<id>/usageRights throws 500 error about 30% of the time (I know it's beta but that seem very high)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have an app that calls `graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<id>/usageRights` API and my logs show that it fails about 30% of the time. I know it's an "unsupported" beta endpoint but this seems like a lot of "internal server errors", even for a beta.

Asking/reporting this because if the `usageRights` API ever goes to the `/1.0` endpoint it seems like something that should be addressed. (I hope usageRights goes to `/1.0` at some point soon as it's been in beta for over 3 years.)

Note that a certain percentage of the time a retry a couple seconds later actually succeeds to it's not an issue with the API invocation. I intend to put a retry for the 500's in code but still seems like a lot of 500 failures to deal with.

Is there a better way to handle this?